# Count instances of many to many relationship : Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a database setup where you have a lecturer having many groups and each group having many students and also a student can be in many groups. Therefore I have a one to many relationship between a lecturer and groups (respectively) and a many to many relationship between students and groups.

I want to show the lecturer how many students they have overall. For example if the lecturer has 5 groups with 5 students in each then I want to show 25. I tried this `auth()->user()->userable->groups()->withCount('students')` but I got this:

> Call to a member function getRelationExistenceCountQuery() on null

**Edited, Here are the relationships:**

```
# user model
class User extends Authenticatable{
   public function userable(){
      return $this->morphTo();
   }
}

# staff/lecturer model
Staff extends Model {
   public function user(){
       return $this->morphOne(User::class, 'userable');
   }

   public function groups(){
      return $this->hasMany(Group::class);
   }
}

#group model
class Group extends Model {
   public function staff(){
      return $this->belongsTo(Staff::class);
   }
   public function students(){
      $this->belongsToMany(Student::class, 'groups_students', 'group_id');
   }
}

# student model
class Student extends Model {
   public function groups(){
       return $this->belongsToMany(Group::class, 'groups_students', 'student_id');
   }
}
```

What's the most efficient way to get my desired result?

Comment: Please post your relationships and the whole query.

Comment: I do not want to add too much code to my question @JonasStaudenmeir, so you'll see that I explained the relationships clearly. And that one line of code was the entire query

Comment: Please post the relationships anyway.

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir There I posted them

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir  No I execute it just as you see it like this: `auth()->user()->userable->groups()->withCount('students')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Group::students()` is missing the `return` statement:

```
public function students(){
   return $this->belongsToMany(Student::class, 'groups_students', 'group_id');
   ^^^^^^
}
```

You can get the total of number of students like this:

```
$groups = auth()->user()->userable->groups()->withCount('students')->pluck('students_count');
$count = $groups->sum();
```

Comment: Thanks itreturned returned a HasMany instance and when I add `->count()` it gives me an incorrect result `auth()->user()->userable->groups()->withCount('students')->count()` I want to know the total of all students in all the groups combined.

Comment: When I add `->get()` it just returns all the groups

Comment: I extended my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help I changed `$groups->sum('students_count');` to jus `$groups->sum();` and it worked